# ETL process with Access and excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

im new to Access and im currently designing a contact database for a client. The assumption is that the client has almost no knowdledge of excel and barely knows the name Access.

One feature the client WANTS (wich i dont recomend) is that users be able to import lots data from excel with apropiate structure and in one botton replace existing records and add new records on to tables.

The macro i have plane looks like this:

1.- Load Excel data on recordset in access.

2.- loop through all values doing:

2.1- validating data structure and values.

2.2- If record is OK, then search for CONTACTID in table, if found, use UPDATE SQL statement, if not found, INSERT SQL statement

2.3 if record is NOT OK, then save on different record source. Lets call it ERROR RS

3. After all records are cheked, insert, updates and/or save on Error RS, ouput different record source as excel file (as a report of records that didnt load)

This is the best idea i have for the time beign, but in practice is a very long expensive code and prone to errors.

Maybe someone can point me to a better way? this seems like something access should have a function for.

Comment: The database should be responsible for data integrity, not the calling code. Write the records one by one and catch the errors from the inserts.

Comment: how would i go about catching errors?  can you point mi to some literature? Some values have validation rules in de DB, some should be numeric and other strings.